# Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page

```
//App.js File

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const App = () => {
  return (

    <Router >
      <Routes>

        <Route path="/" component={ Home }></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>


  )
}

export default App;
```

**My any react router related code not working i don't know why it happend when i start insert some route in program so it show this error**

Comment: Adding a couple of sources that helped me: [React Router v6](https://remix.run/blog/react-router-v6) and the corresponding [GitHub thread](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8146#issuecomment-947860640)

Answer (score 378):

In V6, you can't use the `component` prop anymore. It was replaced in favor of `element`:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
```

More info in the [migration doc](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#advantages-of-route-element).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could not solve this problem for a long time. Thanks to you, I successfully solved the problem! @tavoyne

Comment: Its confusing because the `component` prop shows up in Typescript types for v6.

Comment: I wish this post were more visible, it took me a while to find it

Comment: what if you are trying to pass props? Can you write it like this? ``<Route path="/" element={ props=>(<Home />)}></Route>``

Answer (score 72):

I had the same problem. Replace component with element and it worked.

Replace this:

```js
<Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
```

with this:

```js
<Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} exact />
```

Comment: I want to pass a data to a function inside `<HomePage/>`. How to do it? I tried, 
`<Route exact path="/" render={ ( props ) => ( <ContactList { ...props } contacts={ contacts } getContactId={ removeContactHandler } /> )}/>` but the page became blank with no errors but warning as, `Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.`

Comment: that's what I am trying to do but the data is not showing, only a blank screen.

Comment: @AlexAntoine & CommonMan either of you figure out how to do this.. I am trying to do the same thing with the render attribute.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same error however my fix was slightly different
I had spelled element wrong.

```
<Route exact path='/MyGames' element={<MyGames/>}/>
```

and this was the error it gave me in the browser console

`Matched leaf route at location "/MyGames" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.`

Comment: You right, in current version component doesn't work, I used element and work for me

Comment: Thank you! My first reaction was "how can this be a solution, if you mistype 'element' than React should give you a proper error". But when I check my code i typed "elemenet" =) Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Very simple:

1. use `element` instead of `component`
2. wrap the your component like this: `{<Home/>}` instead of `{Home}`

```js
<Route path="/" component={ <Home/> } />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hmm... what is the point of this change? Just to make it more explicit? Also as of version 6, you can't use component anymore, now you have to use `element`.

Answer (score 10):

in version 6:

component replaced with `element` and needs to close `"</Route>"`

```
 <Route exact path="/" element={<AddTutorial />}></Route>
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Comment: How do you pass params props in `<AddTutorial />`?

Comment: what if you are trying to pass props? Can you write it like this? ```<Route path="/" element={ props=>(<Home />)}></Route>```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
<Route path='/about' component={About} />
```

I used

```
<Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
```

to resolve my problem and now working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem if you are using react-router-dom V6 in your react app.
To solve this it's simple

In your code
Replace component with element
Replace  `{home}`  with `{<home/>}`

This becomes...
`<Route path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>`

This will definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-router-dom 6 or above, you may have a routes array that includes parent and child routes. You may then try to open a route such as

`/portal`

and get this error because that component corresponds to a child route

`/:customerid/portal`

but you haven't read your routes (and their child routes) closely enough to see that.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have reached this point while using a Route where you don't need an element, in my case, I opted to include a solitary "element".

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

In my case, I needed a route item but didn't need it to receive an element because the path I used only serves as an anchor for the same interface. I didn't need the route to load an element.