# "Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element"

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page. I have this error in my console.

```
<Route exact path="/" render= { props => ( <ProductList {...props} products={this.state.products} addToCart={this.addToCart} curretCategory={this.state.curretCategory} info={productInfo} /> )} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854011/matched-leaf-route-at-location-does-not-have-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same code, this place will help you.

LINK : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71602986/17546497

CODE:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  element={< ProductList products = {
  this.state.products
}
currentCategory = {
  this.state.currentCategory
}
addToCart = {
  this.addToCart
}
info = {
  productInfo
} />}/>
```