# React Router does not seem to work anymore using previous method

Tags: reactjs

My previous method of using router in my site does not seem to be working anymore. Below is the code snippet that is being used.

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

import Main from "./main"
import Home from "./home"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h2>The</h2>
        <h1>SportsForge</h1>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
          </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Installed the router in the main folder as well as the src just as back up

`npm install -S react-router-dom`

Error received when installing the router

```
up to date, audited 1570 packages in 6s

173 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

And this is the main.js file

```
import './App.css';

function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Main</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

I did see that in December 2021 something changed with the router setup as well as my version was initially different and that also caused some issue. I do know that if I remove the router and directly show the component it will display properly.

Get the following error in console:

```
router.ts:11 Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
```

Without the Router this renders just fine.

Comment: This is not an error message. Do you get any other message?

Comment: Only other thing I get is to do the npm audit.

Within devtools I see the following
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/main.f3d484fe54bef4502766.hot-update.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
bundle.js:41473 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:

Comment: router.ts:11 Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the div inside the Router, no element should wrap Router and you are missing Routes if you have multiple pages in the Router

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
<Router>
   <div className="App">
     <p>Test</p>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component = {Main} />
          <Route exact path="/create" component = {CreateAccount}/>
          <Route exact path="/home" component = {Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/leagues" component = {Leagues}/>
          <Route exact path="/games" component = {Games}/>
       </Routes>
    </Router>
  <p>v1.041522</p>
</div>
```

Routes acts like Switch in react router dom v5

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/">
           <HomePage />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/blog/:slug">
           <BlogPost />
       </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>,
```

Comment: Updated the code block above which gets the basic setup working but the imported components are still not showing.

Comment: you probably don't import properly, need to add 2 dots if you get out of the current folder or 1 dot if you go down or in the same folder eg: "../folder3/folder2/ddsfs.js" or "./folder4/fdd.js"

Comment: Yeah all same folder.....seems like I have not imported the router correctly....Also get a weird message after doing npm start....shows up for a few secs so hard to capture it.... I will also update the main thread with the app.js and main just so you see

Comment: Also looked back at a known working site I built a few months back and that also no longer works....

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the React Router Version you installed is version 6 which changes the structure of the react components.

[stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854011/matched-leaf-route-at-location-does-not-have-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out. Appears I am working on v6 and the issue was in the route, the component is no longer used and had to be replaced with element