# I am facing the problem with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

File `App.jsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import Master from "./Master";
import Appone from "./appone";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "reactrouter-dom";
const App = () => {
return (
  <Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" component={<Master />} exact ></Route>
    <Route path="/days" component={<Appone />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>);};
export default App;
```

if anyone wants to see the complete code it is in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weekly-sheduler-forked-2mbogb)

Basically, I am trying to make a two page react app so I am using routes and route tag that you can see in the codesandox but I am getting the error as

```
"Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page. 
    in Routes (created by App)
    in App"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854011/matched-leaf-route-at-location-does-not-have-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v6+, they had to replace `component` with `element` as `<Route children>` is reserved for nesting routes...There are some other arguments too as of why they changed it and you can read more about that over [here.](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#advantages-of-route-element)

So to answer to your question, maybe this is what you want:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Master />} exact ></Route>
<Route path="/days" element={<Appone />}></Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links

Short, update to match this:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Master />} />
        <Route path="/days" element={<Appone />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```